# Modifying a file at a specific line in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader, fileoutputstream

I'm writing a method that will allow me to input a line at a specific point in a file, such as a .txt or .vbs script. The problem I'm having is the writing back part, the output file is blank- not containing the entries of my ArrayList scriptCollection. Here is my test method code;

```
public void testMethod()throws Exception 
{

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/jchild/Desktop/PrintScript.vbs"));
  int indexNo = 1; 
  int appendAt=0;  
  String line;            
  while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
  {            
      scriptCollection.add(line);
      if(line.contains("Add at this point"))
      {
          System.out.println("Successfully read and compared"); //this is just for test output
          appendAt = appendAt + indexNo;
      }
      indexNo++;
   }   
  br.close();
  scriptCollection.add(appendAt++,"Appended here"); 
  System.out.println(scriptCollection.toString()); //this is just for test output

  //here's what's causing the problem
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/jchild/Desktop/PrintScript.txt"); 
  PrintWriter is = new PrintWriter(fos);
  for(String temp : scriptCollection) 
  {
      is.println(temp);
  }                     
  scriptCollection.clear();
}
```

Comment: 1) you need to flush and close the outputstream. 2) did you check if this line ```is.println(temp);``` is executed with some data?

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the streams.